# Portal Express v8 installation failed

Tags: websphere-portal

I have downloaded Portal Express v8 installation trail version from IBM and wen i start installing this using Installation manager 'IBM Websphere Application Server Network Deployment v8' got installed successfully but it failed when installing 'IBM Websphere Portal Express v8'. I tried 3/4 times the same happened every time. I have attached required screenshots and error log file. Please help me in resolving this issue.

Error message is :
Error during "post-install configure" phase:
   Error executing the C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\wp_profile\ConfigEngine\ConfigEngine.bat command: status=1. 
 For more information, see the agent log file: C:\ProgramData\IBM\Installation Manager\logs\native\20131129_0642.log

Error log url : [Error log file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fqsd3jlahk91e7j/20131129_0642.log)
TIA

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problems installing the Portal express.

The trick is to install the software using a LOCAL Admin account.
You would need to log out of the Domain, login into the target computer with a Local administrative account and repeat the process.  The Portal express will install fine.

Also ensure that the local administrative account belongs to the 2 DB2 groups created by portal express.
DB2Admin
DB2Users

I found this after repeated trial and error attempts.

DB2 cannot check with the network servers while installing the database, hence it can only work with a local administrator account.

Comment: thanks for the reply.....i tried many times. But everytime i am facing different issues...what do you mean by 'local administrative account'. I am the administrator for my system.  [click here for screeshot](http://postimg.org/image/9ty8x7oex/)

Answer (score 0):

According to logs you have a problem with database installation. Error code is -554 SQLSTATE=42502 you can read error description here http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z9.doc.codes%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fn554.htm

I think problem in user **pjami**, make sure that user belong to Administrators group or db2admins group.

Comment: Hi Georgy,
Thanks for the reply.....'pjami' belongs for Administrators group only. ![Click here for screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/9ty8x7oex/).

Comment: I don't know what exactly problem you have. Pls read installation docs and check every step related user and/or database